# Solace: How to switch off the info statements sent to std err from solace java api

Tags: solace

currently seeing the following lines when running the solace client.

```
10-Feb-2016 11:14:13 com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel    call
INFO: Connecting to host 'orig=myhost.com, host=solacehost.com, port=55555'  (host 1 of 1, smfclient 4, attempt 1 of 1, this_host_attempt: 1 of 1)
```

Looked into JCSMPProperties class to control this but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution the solace API uses various logging libs, my project had commons-logging. Suppressing the log output was quite straight forward after knowing that using

```
static {
      System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.Log",
                         "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog");
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Solace Java API uses Jakarta Commons Logging to support different logging
frameworks, such as log4j or java.util.logging for the application’s logging
framework.

You will need to identify what is the exact logging framework used by your application, and adjust the log level for the Solace API.

For example, if your application is using log4j, you can edit your `log4j.properties` file to set the log level of the Solace API to WARN, to hide those info level logs.

`log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender`
`log4j.logger.com.solacesystems.jcsmp=WARN, A1`

Comment: thanks @RussellSim for the input, found that project was using common-logging and suppressed the log output.